# Select non-adjacent column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I want to search value of B which is based on Vb(Zone). I'm using VLOOKUP() to search in Zone column in A and as well as B. In VLOOKUP() table array would be 'A2:C7' for be B, but how do I avoid column A(B2:B7)?

[image: Selection Area]

Comment: for `A`: `=VLOOKUP(G1,A:C,2,FALSE)` and for `B`: `=VLOOKUP(G1,A:C,3,FALSE)`

Comment: Maybe try to get into the habit of using `INDEX` in combination of `MATCH` > `=INDEX(B$2:C$7,MATCH($G$1;A$2:A$7,0),MATCH(F2;B$1:C$1,0))`. Allthough it may look more complicated. It's actually good practice =)